# Pricing for specific Googleway commands in RStudio

Tags: r, google-places-api, googleway

I am currently using the Google Places API on a free trial. I am interested in paying for the API but can't find the exact cost of the two commands that I use: `google_places()`, and `google_place_details()`. I have contacted the Google sales team and looked at the [places and billing url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing), but I have not managed to find the answer of how much it would cost exactly to execute these two commands.

For `google_places()`, this is an example of a command I would execute:

```
google_places(search_string = "Cafeteria in Madrid, Spain", key=key)
```

From the places and billing url, it seems like this counts as a [text search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#text-search), so each time the code is executed it would cost 0,032$. Is this the case?

For `google_place_details()`, here is an example of the command I would execute:

```
google_place_details(place_id = "ChIJf_XA-F0U04kR1IPYSdTJ4so", key=key)
```

This command, as well giving basic place details (which cost 0,017$ according to the billing url),
gives information which counts as contact data (an extra 0,003$) and atmosphere data (an extra 0,005$). It also provides photo data (0,007$ according to the billing url), which I am not interested in but is automatically included in the results anyway. Does this mean that the cost of executing this command once is these four prices summed up?

I am interested in knowing exactly how much it would cost to execute the two commands I have listed.

Answer (score 0):

probably this helps:

First of all you are billed monthly after you exceeded the 200 Euro/Dollars, which are given by google for free (as you probably described as "free plan"). So after every month you get a bill on how many requests of each function you send to google. There everything is written quite clearly including the amount and price of each "unit". then you can easily divide it.

Second option would be your [Google Api Cockpit](https://console.cloud.google.com).

It tracks your requests quite precisely on different time bases. So sending your wanted commands only once on a day can give you an exact total-price.

The Cockpit is super handy for different things. If you want you can even set limits, which is probably helpful in your case too.

Here is the link to the billing monitor as well: [Billing Google API Cockpit](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing)

Furthermore the description of how google charges you. Look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing?hl=en)

best regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33259866)